# Difficulty with SharedPreference data storage and losing values on exit

Tags: android

I am having trouble storing primitive data in an instance of SharedPreferences. Everything works as I thought it would, but when I close or exit my app and reopen it, the values in the SharedPreference go back to the default states.

I think it may have to do with either where or how I set the default values. Here is the snippet I am referring to that resides in the onCreate() of my main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        userDetails = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
        edit.putInt("list_code", 0);    //stores the number corresponding to a word list
        edit.putInt("highscore", 0);    //stores the starting score
        edit.commit();
    }
```

Thougts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bundle != null` when your activity "restarts". For instance when screen was rotated or system killed background activity and recreated it. Otherwise it equals `null`. So to save some data between different instances of activity you need to check whether you save data before or not.

Sample:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
int highScore = preferences.getInt("highscore", -1);

if (highScore == -1) {
    //preferences was never used, so put default value
    highScore = 0;
    preferences.edit().putInt("highscore", highScore).commit();
}
```

Comment: faster by a couple of seconds.
also this answer adds some light
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5901770/1368705